# Datagridview in vb.net not displaying everything in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Ok so im new to dataviews. im using it to display everything in my MYSQL database, but its just a gray box on my vb.net page. whats wrong with my code??

```
     Public Sub dataview()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
    Dim bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
    Try
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM upload", db_con)
        Dim da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        bindingSource1.DataSource = dt

        With Me.DataGridView1
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = bindingSource1

            .AutoSizeRowsMode = 
             DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
        End With
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("something went wrong")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check your connection string? Debug and check the variable and make sure it's not empty or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems with bindingsources this line usually does the trick.

```
bindingSource1.ResetBindings(True)
```

If this doesn't work you should put a breakpoint in the code where the datatable is created to see if that even contains data.